# How to let Clients know about new HostedRoom in Smack?

Tags: java, openfire, smack

I am working with Openfire and Smack, currently creating new system MultiUserChat rooms. How I tell clients that new system room had been created(deleted) on the server? (I need clients to modify their's Rosters)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a 'challenge'. A server doesn't send a message to the clients to inform about new rooms - like the presence messages for users. It's the clients responsibility to explore the service (like 'conference') and look for new rooms.

So a general solution for all possible clients will not work. If you developed the client by yourself, you could implement an additional notification service. That would require implementing an openfire plugin, that listens to 'room modification' events and sends a custom message to your clients that will react with updating the room list.